# Java: adding info from one array to another

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I just started learning Java with the goal to make games for Android. I'm taking an online course, where I am provided with a task and later an evaluation of some sort.

This is what I've done so far:

```
public String[] pie;
public Scanner x;
public String[] name;
public String[] name1;
public String[] name2;
public int[] year;
public int[] numb;
public String[] language;
public boolean[] read;
public int[] rating;

   public void openfile(){
    try{x = new Scanner(new File("Raamatukogu.txt"));}
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("no file was found");}}

public void readfil(){
    while(x.hasNext()){
        String rida = x.nextLine();
        pie = rida.split("#");
        for(int i = 0; i < pie.length ; i++){
```

What I would like to do is to add something like this to my code, but automated:

```
name[0] = pie[0]
name1[0] = pie[1]
name2[0] = pie[2]
year[0] = pie[3]
numb[0] = pie[4]
language[0] = pie[5]
read[0] = pie[6]
rating[0] = pie[7]

name[1] = pie[8]
name1[1] = pie[9]
name2[1] = pie[10]
year[1] = pie[11]
numb[1] = pie[12]
language[1] = pie[13]
read[1] = pie[14]
rating[1] = pie[15]

name[2] = pie[16]
name1[2] = pie[17]
...}
```

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<pie.length;i++){
    name[j] = pie[0];
    name1[j] = pie[1];
    name2[j] = pie[2];
    year[j] = pie[3];
    numb[j] = pie[4];
    language[j] = pie[5];
    read[j] = pie[6];
    rating[j] = pie[7];
    j++;
}
```

Comment: That should do it. So embarrassed that I didn't see that myself :P. Also, for anyone looking at this question, you should also add pie[0 + i], pie[1+i], pie[2+i], pie[3+i]..

Answer (score 0):

Here's two sides of the same coin.  Both assume `pie.length` is a multiple of 8, since your code also appears to assume that.

```
for (int i=0; i<pie.length/8; i++) {
    int index = i * 8;
    name[i] = pie[index];
    name1[i] = pie[index+1];
    name2[i] = pie[index+2];
    year[i] = pie[index+3];
    numb[i] = pie[index+4];
    language[i] = pie[index+5];
    read[i] = pie[index+6];
    rating[i] = pie[index+7];
}
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<pie.length; i=i+8) {
    int index = i/8;
    name[index] = pie[i];
    name1[index] = pie[i+1];
    name2[index] = pie[i+2];
    year[index] = pie[i+3];
    numb[index] = pie[i+4];
    language[index] = pie[i+5];
    read[index] = pie[i+6];
    rating[index] = pie[i+7];
}
```